# Filter one variable from an NSArray with many instances

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nspredicate

I'm at the beginning  of Objective-C and I'm clueless about my problem

I have a class and I want to filter from an `NSArray` that includes different instances of class `Employee` just one variable of instances, `name`

*Employee.h*

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Employee : NSObject
@property NSString *name ;
@property int age;
@end
```

*Employee.m*

```
#import "Employee.h"

@implementation Employee
@synthesize name ;
@synthesize age;
@end
```

*main.m*

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Employee.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        Employee *firstEmployee = [[Employee alloc] init];
        [firstEmployee setAge:35];
        [firstEmployee setName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"George "]];

        Employee *secondEmployee = [[Employee alloc] init];
        [secondEmployee setAge:35];
        [secondEmployee setName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Ivan "]];

        Employee *thirdEmployee = [[Employee alloc] init];
        [thirdEmployee setAge:35];
        [thirddEmployee setName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Ivan "]];

        NSMutableArray *yesArray =                                                         
        [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:firstEmployee, secondEmployee, thirdEmployee, nil];
        int i;
        int count;
        count = [yesArray count];

        for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
            NSLog(@"Name of %i is %@", i, [[yesArray objectAtIndex:i] name]);
            NSLog(@"Age of  %i is %i", i, [[yesArray objectAtIndex:i] age]);
            NSPredicate *bPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] 'j'"];
            // I don't know how to access just name
            NSArray *beginWithB = [[yesArray name]  filteredArrayUsingPredicate:bPredicate]; 
         }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please let me know if you need more information! - Otherwise, if an answer helped, you can "accept" it by clicking on the check mark. That marks the problem as solved and gives some "reputation points" to you and to the author of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

To get a list of employees, filtered by name, use

```
NSPredicate *bPredicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name BEGINSWITH[c] %@", @"I"];
NSArray *beginWith1 = [yesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:bPredicate1];
```

To get an array containing only the employee names, use

```
NSArray *namesOnly = [yesArray valueForKey:@"name"];
```

This array can be filtered using

```
NSPredicate *bPredicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH[c] %@", @"I"];
NSArray *beginWith2 = [namesOnly filteredArrayUsingPredicate:bPredicate2];
```